# types.NewTx instead of types.NewTransaction

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

```
        var data []byte
        tx := types.NewTransaction(nonce, toAddress, value, gasLimit, gasPrice, data)
        signedTx, err := types.SignTx(tx, types.HomesteadSigner{}, privateKey)
```

`NewTransaction` is deprecated, so must to use `NewTx` instead.

I didn't get how to create TxData for `NewTx(inner TxData) *Transaction` function.

Is there any function that returns TxData?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create - DynamicTx/ AccessListTx or LegacyTx types. Checkout this source code to see how to create them -

https://github.com/nnqq/geth-tx-hash-bug/blob/master/main.go