# replacement transaction underpriced while deploying

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, contract-deployment, gas-price

I am attempting to deploy a contract to an address that I generated. I use

> https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/

as my test net. This is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jimlawless/whereami"
    "log"
    "math/big"
    "system/wallets"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "system/contracts/api"
)

func deployContract() {
    fmt.Println(whereami.WhereAmI())
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(wallets.GetTestWallet().PrivateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("cannot assert type: publicKey is not of type *ecdsa.PublicKey")
    }

    fromAddress := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA)
    nonce, err := client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }

    gasPrice, err := client.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }

    auth := bind.NewKeyedTransactor(privateKey)
    //https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/104085/types-newtx-instead-of-types-newtransaction

    auth.Nonce = big.NewInt(int64(nonce))
    auth.Value = big.NewInt(0)       // in wei
    auth.GasLimit = uint64(GasLimit) // in units 1000000
    auth.GasPrice = gasPrice

    address, deployTx, instance, err := api.DeployApi(auth, client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }
    fmt.Println("deployTx: ", deployTx.Hash())
    fmt.Println("address: ", address)

    key := [32]byte{}
    value := [32]byte{}
    copy(key[:], []byte("foo2"))
    copy(value[:], []byte("bar2"))

    assignTx, err := instance.SetItem(auth, key, value)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)//<--replacement transaction underpriced

    }

    fmt.Println("tx sent: ", assignTx.Hash().Hex())

    result, err := instance.Items(nil, key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(result[:])) // "bar"
}
```

I get a new **deployTx** hash on every request. I have tried increasing gas price, removed and increased nonce. Same error.

Any ideas???

Comment: You have to increment the nonce between the contract deployment and executing a method from it.